# Obtaining non-infinite expression for definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, asymptotics

$$R^*=(\int_{0}^1 \frac{\psi^n}{(1+\lambda\psi^m)}d\psi)^{0.5}$$

Where n, m, and $\lambda$ are all constants.

Assuming that $n-m\ge0$, and $\lambda > 100$, we obtain:

$$R^*=(\int_{0}^1 \frac{\psi^n}{(\lambda\psi^m)}d\psi)^{0.5}=(\frac{1/\lambda}{(n-m+1)})^{0.5}$$

My issue is with this part. Evaluate when $n-m+1=0$ and $n-m+1<0$

For the first part I think we can say that:

$$R^*=(\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{(\lambda\psi)}d\psi)^{0.5}=ln(1)^{0.5}-ln(0)^{0.5}=\infty$$

And for the second part:

$$R^*=(\int_{0}^1 \frac{\psi^{n-m}}{\lambda}d\psi)^{0.5}=\frac{1^{n-m+1}-0^{n-m+1}}{(n-m+1)\lambda}$$

Which is $\infty$ also.

Apparently there is some way to evaluate this where the result is NOT infinity, but I have no idea what the approach is supposed to be. The only hint I have is that the denominator must approach 1 when concentration ($\psi$) approaches zero, even when $\lambda$ is large in the original expression. Does this mean that I cannot drop 1 from the original expression? In that case the solution is the hypergeometric function, which I'm also pretty sure isn't what I'm supposed to do.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Do you know anything about asymptotic expansions of integrals? This is a pretty standard problem in the area of non-uniformity of asymptotic expansions of integrals (namely $1$ is only much less than $\lambda \psi^m$ for $\psi$ much larger than $\lambda^{-1/m}$, assuming $m>0$).

Comment: @Ian Unfortunately, no. Any recommended reading?

Comment: If the question is in fact about getting an approximation for fixed $m, n$ and large $\lambda$, then, for $-1 < n < m - 1$, make the change of variables $\psi = \lambda^{-1/m} u$ and extend the interval of integration to infinity.

Comment: @Maxim how'd you come up with this? I'm not sure what you mean by fixed. I was trying to come up with an expression that would be valid for any n-m+1<0. With n and m > 0. That WASN'T a special function. Apparently that didn't exist though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **may** not drop anything which would change a "trivial" integral to an improper integral. Would you do it for
$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x}$ ?

The case where $m=n+1$ is quite simple
$$\int_{0}^1 \frac{\psi^n}{1+\lambda\,\psi^{n+1}}\,d\psi$$ since the numerator is "almost" the derivative of the denominator. Then, ???

**Edit**

For the most general case, you can write
$$I=\int_{0}^1 \frac{\psi^n}{1+\lambda\,\psi^{n+1}}\,d\psi=\int_{0}^1 {\psi^n}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k \lambda ^k \psi ^{k m}\right)\,d\psi=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k \frac{ \lambda ^k}{k m+n+1}$$ which can be expressed as
$$I=\frac{\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{n+1}{m};\frac{m+n+1}{m};-\lambda \right)}{n+1}\qquad \text{or} \qquad I=\frac{\Phi \left(-\lambda ,1,\frac{n+1}{m}\right)}{m}$$ where appear the gaussian hypergeometric function and the Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent function.

Comment: Thanks. I see it's possible to do a straight forward u-substitution in that case. Do you have a suggestion for the other case?

Comment: @user8151560. Have a look at my edit. I don't think that you can avoid special functions or infinite summations (which are the same).